# google speech api response is empty, even with this example test

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

When I run the API explorer from this page i get a 200 OK response, but the response json doesn't have any transcription. What am i doing wrong?

API Explorer location:
https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1/speech/longrunningrecognize

Request parameters:
Default

Request body:

```
 {
   "config": {
     "encoding": "FLAC",
     "languageCode": "en-US",
     "sampleRateHertz": 16000
   },
   "audio": {
     "uri": "gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac"
   }
 }
```

Response:

```
{
  "name": "3497944051092250866"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out.

with longrunningrecognize you get back the name object and then you have to send a operations.get to retrieve your processed object.

this is explained here beautifully
https://medium.com/towards-data-science/tutorial-asynchronous-speech-recognition-in-python-b1215d501c64

Comment: Unusefull.

'const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(recognizeRequest);
resultArray = await operation.promise();
`
returns empty